# How can I stop renamed items being italic?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, typography

Something that is really annoying me about Minecraft 1.13 is the fact that all renamed items are italic, and I cannot seem to try and figure out how to make it 'normal'. It was never like this in any previous versions, is there any way of fixing this? An example of what I mean can be found below.

The ItemStack code:

```
ItemStack emerald = new ItemStack(Material.SPAWNER);
ItemMeta emeraldMeta = emerald.getItemMeta();
emeraldMeta.setDisplayName(Main.colorCodes("&3&l» &aEmerald Golem Spawner &3&l«"));
emeraldMeta.setLore(emeraldLore);
emerald.setItemMeta(emeraldMeta);
```

The item inside of a GUI (as you can see, the name is in italic):

[image: It's italic...]

Comment: Could you show us the code from Main.colorCodes?

Comment: Sure thing:
@Kerooker
(Sorry I have literally no idea how to format these replys.......)


 public static String colorCodes(String s) {
  return ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', s);
 }

Comment: I thought that it maybe added the italics code by mistake. Check my answer below

Comment: You should edit your question to add that relevant information, @Askingg

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread in Spigot forums](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/1-13-item-display-name-problem-italizied.330429/#post-3085847), this is a bug within Spigot/Minecraft.

There are a couple of issues referring to this in Mojang's Issue Tracker ([1](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-134588), [2](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-124458)).

---

Currently, the only way to fix it is to update your **Spigot Version**, according to user RockinChaos from the thread I quoted above.

You can build the latest Spring following [this tutorial from Spring MC](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/)

Comment: Exactly. Basically that. I added some more context to the answer for future users reference, and if the new build isn't downloadable, you should build it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Add &r before &3&l.